# Add Div to Comment Form

Tags: customization, comments, forms, validation

I have some code that displays my comment form and my custom validation, what I'd like to do is add a div right underneath the title, but I'm not sure how to do that because that code is generated...

The Code:

```
<?php $comment_args = array(
    'title_reply' => 'Leave a Comment', 
    'comment_notes_before' => '',  
    'fields' => apply_filters( 'comment_form_default_fields', array(
    'author' => '<p class="comment-form-author">' . '<label for="author">' . __( 'Name:' ) . '</label> ' . ( $req ? '<span>*</span>' : '' ) .
    '<input id="author" name="author" type="text" value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author'] ) . '" size="30" required /></p>', 
    'email'  => '<p class="comment-form-email">' .
    '<label for="email">' . __( 'E-mail:' ) . '</label> ' . ( $req ? '<span>*</span>' : '' ) .
    '<input id="email" name="email" type="text" value="' . esc_attr(  $commenter['comment_author_email'] ) . '" size="30" required />'.'</p>', 
    'url'    => '' ) ), 
    'comment_field' => '<p>' . '<label for="comment">' . __( 'Comment:' ) . '</label>' . '<textarea id="comment" name="comment" cols="45" rows="8" required></textarea>' . '</p>', 
    'comment_notes_after' => '', 
    'label_submit' => __( 'Post' ),
    );
    comment_form($comment_args);
?>
```

Which Outputs:

```
<h3 id="reply-title" class="comment-reply-title">Leave a Comment <small><a rel="nofollow" id="cancel-comment-reply-link" href="/93/#respond" style="display:none;">Cancel reply</a></small></h3>

<form action="http://ourpictureshare.com/wp-comments-post.php" method="post" id="commentform" class="comment-form">
      <p class="logged-in-as">Logged in as <a href="http://ourpictureshare.com/wp-admin/profile.php">admin</a>. <a href="http://ourpictureshare.com/wp-login.php?action=logout&amp;redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fourpictureshare.com%2F93%2F&amp;_wpnonce=e330f94e35" title="Log out of this account">Log out?</a></p>
      <p><label for="comment">Comment:</label><textarea id="comment" name="comment" cols="45" rows="8" required=""></textarea></p>                                              
      <p class="form-submit">
          <input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="Post">
          <input type="hidden" name="comment_post_ID" value="93" id="comment_post_ID">
          <input type="hidden" name="comment_parent" id="comment_parent" value="0">
      </p>
      <input type="hidden" id="_wp_unfiltered_html_comment_disabled" name="_wp_unfiltered_html_comment" value="70754f57d7"><script>(function(){if(window===window.parent){document.getElementById('_wp_unfiltered_html_comment_disabled').name='_wp_unfiltered_html_comment';}})();</script>
</form>
```

What I am looking for:

```
<h3 id="reply-title" class="comment-reply-title">Leave a Comment <small><a rel="nofollow" id="cancel-comment-reply-link" href="/93/#respond" style="display:none;">Cancel reply</a></small></h3>

<!-- I added this line --> <div id="MY_DIV_HERE"></div> <!-- I added this line -->

<form action="http://ourpictureshare.com/wp-comments-post.php" method="post" id="commentform" class="comment-form">
    <p class="logged-in-as">Logged in as <a href="http://ourpictureshare.com/wp-admin/profile.php">admin</a>. <a href="http://ourpictureshare.com/wp-login.php?action=logout&amp;redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fourpictureshare.com%2F93%2F&amp;_wpnonce=e330f94e35" title="Log out of this account">Log out?</a></p>
    <p><label for="comment">Comment:</label><textarea id="comment" name="comment" cols="45" rows="8" required=""></textarea></p>                                              
    <p class="form-submit">
        <input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="Post">
        <input type="hidden" name="comment_post_ID" value="93" id="comment_post_ID">
        <input type="hidden" name="comment_parent" id="comment_parent" value="0">
  </p>
  <input type="hidden" id="_wp_unfiltered_html_comment_disabled" name="_wp_unfiltered_html_comment" value="70754f57d7"><script>(function(){if(window===window.parent){document.getElementById('_wp_unfiltered_html_comment_disabled').name='_wp_unfiltered_html_comment';}})();</script>
</form>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Josh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add some custom HTML between the `</h3>` and the `<form>` tags, you can try the following:

```
/**
 * Add custom HTML between the `</h3>` and the `<form>` tags in the comment_form() output.
 */
add_action( 'comment_form_before', function(){
    add_filter( 'pre_option_comment_registration', 'wpse_156112' );
});

function wpse_156112( $comment_registration )
{
     // Adjust this to your needs:
     echo '<div>Custom HTML between the closing H3 and opening FORM tags.</div>'; 

    remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );
    return $comment_registration;
}
```

where the output is:

```
...</h3>
<div>Custom HTML between the closing H3 and opening FORM tags.</div>
<form>...
```

Otherwise you can use the `comment_form_top` action to add custom HTML right after the opening `<form>` tag:

```
/**
 * Add custom HTML just after the opening `<form>` tag in the comment_form() output.
 */
add_action( 'comment_form_top', function(){
     // Adjust this to your needs:
     echo '<div>Custom HTML just after the opening FORM tag.</div>'; 
});
```

with the following output:

```
<form>
    <div>Custom HTML just after the opening FORM tag.</div>
    ...
```

Here you can see the comment form of the *TwentyTwelve* theme with both methods activated:

[image: comment form]

Comment: This is a great solution, I had tried some jQuery, but because this was displaying validation, when the form submitted my div was gone...this keeps the div there and works like it should - exactly what I was looking for!! Thanks :-)